# Definition of Strong Nash equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Let $(N,S,u)$ be a strategic form game, where

i) $ N = \{ 1,2,3,... n \}$ is the set of players,

ii) $S_i$ is the set of strategies for the $i^{th}$ player, and $ S = S_1 \times S_2 ... \times S_n$

iii) $u_i : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the utility function for the $i^{th}$ player, and $u = (u_1,u_2, ...,u_n)$ is a vector of the $n$ utility functions.

I wish to formally define the concept of a strong Nash equilibrium (SNE) for such a game. (A non-mathematical definition is given on Wikipedia. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Nash_equilibrium )

**My Attempted definition:**

Let $U \subseteq N$ be a non-empty subset of the $n$ players. If $s = (s_1,s_2,...,s_n) \in S$ is a strategy, then let $s_U$ denote the vector of strategies of all the players from U and let $s_{-U}$ denote the vector of strategies of all the players not from U. So $s = (s_U,s_{-U})$.

A strategy $s$ is in strong Nash equilibrium if $! (\exists T \subseteq N, T \neq \phi $ $\&$ $ \exists s' = (s'_T,s_{-T}) \in S, s'_T \neq s_T$ such that $u_i(s') > u_i(s) \forall i \in T $ ).

Is this correct? If not, could someone please give a mathematical definition of SNE without using non-vector matrices and simplices?

Comment: A google search shows there's a definition in here: https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/~plc/sestri/lucchetti2014.pdf.

Comment: @palmpo I had read that definition before asking the question - however that definition uses $m \times n \times .... n$ matrices and simplices, which I couldn't understand - hence I put that in the question above.

Comment: My basic query is this: 
A strategy is a strong equilibrium if

(i) No non-empty coalition can deviate such that each member of the coalition strictly increases their utility.

(OR) (ii)  No non-empty coalition can deviate such that each member of the coalition increases their utility where atleast one member strictly increases their utility.

Which definition is correct?

Comment: Aumann (1959) stated the definition of a SNE in form of the latter, that makes reference on the definition of a Pareto optimum. However, definition (i) imposes much stronger requirements on a SNE, if you want it is a SSNE. It is an acceptable modification, hence on cannot say that it is incorrect.

Comment: I don't know anything about SNEs but wouldn't (i) be weaker than (ii)? Any deviation that strictly increases every member's utility surely strictly increases at least one member's utility. So (ii) doesn't allow the deviations of the sort in (i), and more. So SNEs should have (i) while SSNEs should have (ii).

Comment: @palmpo you are right, (i) is weaker than (ii). However, I would stated a little bit different. If there is any deviation that allows an increase of utility of at least one member (ii), then of course, it is not possible to increase it for all members (i). Thus, (i) is a weak SNE. This is the contrapositive of your formulation. My mistake, for negations one should think at least twice.

Comment: The definition of strong Nash equilibrium is problematic. It assumes that players can form coalitions but enforces that the profits of this coalition have to be distributed according to their individual payoff functions $u_i$. This is not plausible. If players can form a coalition, then it is natural to assume that they can also divide profits between them in a reasonable way. For example via a corporate scheme. For instance, players can get their Shapley value and not simply their utility. Anyway, as you have, it adheres to the usual notion, but do not expect to go very far with this notion.